# Magento XML RPC Error

Tags: module, zend-framework

I have created an XML-RPC User and I've assigned a role (with all resources) from admin panel: System/Web Services/XML-Rpc Users and Roles.

Now I want to dump all cart products and send them to an external server.

I'm using this code in app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://mysite/api/xmlrpc/', 80);
$session = $client->call('login', array('myuser', 'myapi'));
$filterData = array('type' => array('in' => 'simple'));
$product = $client->call('call', array($session, 'category_product.list', array($filterData)));
var_dump($product);
$server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('/xmlServer.php','www.server-site.com', 80);
$result = $server->send($product);
```

The problem is that I receive this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getUri() on a non-object in /var/www/html/zzz/lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php on line 265
```

This is the code from line 265:

```
if($http->getUri() === null) {
        $http->setUri($this->_serverAddress);
    }
```

I think that the problem comes from here:

```
$session = $client->call('login', array('myuser', 'myapi'));
```

But the user and api are valid. So I don't know what could it be.
What is wrong in my code?

Anticipated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://mysite/api/xmlrpc/', 80);
```

The second param of `Zend_XmlRpc_Client` is a `Zend_Http_Client` object, not the port number. Change your code to:

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://mysite/api/xmlrpc/');
```

Comment: Now I receive this error: 
There has been an error processing your request

Unable to Connect to tcp://mysite.com:80. Error #113: No route to host

Comment: If I access this page: http://mysite.com/api/xmlrpc/ , I receive this xml error message: <methodResponse><fault><value><struct><member><name>faultCode</name><value><int>630</int></value></member><member><name>faultString</name><value><string>Unable to read request</string></value></member></struct></value></fault></methodResponse>

Comment: This is a sign that it is working if you are accessing it via the browser. You need to do a POST to that page to get relevant information.

Comment: I didn't fixed it yet. But I've found the problem. Php command: file_get_contents return null, so it might be server settings, firewall or something like this. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Pascut please propose your question as an answer and accept it, if possible.

Comment: the problem was the server

Comment: @Pascut - a truly tantalising comment to leave us with. Oh the frustration!!  What was the problem on the server, how did you resolve it?

Comment: The problem was the server setup, the user rights were limited! I tried the function file_get_contents() and it didn't worked. It was a user access restriction. I created a new user with different access and after that it worked.

Comment: @Pascut - What user rights? can you be more specific? Are you talking about owner/group permissions on the server? What/where did you create a new user, FTP user?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you here, the sys admin created a new user for me and after that it worked. I suggest you to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10721576/1564840